# No puedo ejecutar cv2 en python

Tags: python, pip, cv2

Al momento de ejecutar cv2 con import cv2 me aparece lo siguiente:
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
Cuando me voy a pip desde cmd e instalo todo lo necesario para ejecutar cv2 me sale:

```
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-contrib-python in  
c:\users\camb\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.9_qbz 
5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python39\site-packages (4.5.2.54)
```

Ya la verdad se me están agotando los recursos necesito ayuda pronto :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: `pip uninstall opencv-python` y prueba con `pip install opencv-contrib-python` o vuelve a instalarlo, reinicia tus editores y vuelve a intentar

Comment: Intenta actualizando las librerías que tienes instaladas